# What is new Thor's form?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

My question is in regard to Thor's new form, where he has lightning all around him.

If I'm right, this is the King Thor version, but I am not sure.

So, my question is: is this new form his own power or does it have something to do with Odin force?

If it's his own power and now that Odin is gone, what will happen to Odin force?

Comment: Note, I've asked this question from mobile. So if anyone is using it on desktop and knows tricks to update so that the spoilers part is only revealed on hover, please can you update it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless this is addressed in the movie any answer is likely to be opinion-based. The question could be improved to ask if the producers/director/studio have spoken on this issue though.

Comment: @Paulie_D considering the fact that Odin force had not me referred to, in mcu, i don't think this is addressed in the movie. Also i have not followed any interview so not sure in this area as well. I thought someone with proper comic book knowledge might have some answer. Hence i asked. So in this case it is not an opinionated question.

Comment: Comic book questions are issues for our sister site on Science Fiction and Fantasy and I'm pretty sure that the Odinforce has been referenced in the MCU

Comment: @Paulie_D ah! Can we flag it to be moved? If not, I'll delete it and post it there once I'm on desktop. Thanks!

Comment: I'll let you delete/repost. I can't flag to migrate without involving a mod and I don't think this needs that. Up to you though.

Comment: The real question is whether it’s even his final form.